# Removing S.M.A.R.T. data recovery virus

Tags: windows, virus, spyware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Computer is infected by a virus or a malware, what do I do now?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now)

I have a virus on my computer. I don't know where it came from, but it says S.M.A.R.T Repair and S.M.A.R.T Data Recovery program have found viruses on my computer and I need to pay for virus removal.

Comment: Punch "remove smart data recovery" into your favorite search engine and you'll get tons of hits on pages like [this one](http://www.2-viruses.com/remove-smart-data-recovery) that explain how to remove it.

Comment: Try what is suggested there, too. If that didn't work, please report back.

Answer (score 1):

Remove smart data recovery like what David Schwartz have said. Then install one of the popular free anti virus such as AVG, Avria, Avast, etc.